# Using Retrofit + OkHttp + Gson the api returns html though postman return json

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, swagger-ui, okhttp

I tested my api in postman and it returns json

just a plain get api

baseurl/ecom-services/api/mobile/tasks/user/**tokenhere_**/upcoming

but on Android

```
  @GET("mobile/tasks/user/{id}/upcoming")
  fun jobList(@Path("id") id: String): retrofit2.Call<Job>
```

this returns an html

onError returns this:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

this is the call

```
 fun fetchData() {
    apiService.jobList(getUserId()).enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<Job>{
      override fun onFailure(call: Call<Job>?, t: Throwable?) {
        Timber.v(t!!.message.toString())
      }
      override fun onResponse(call: Call<Job>?, response: Response<Job>?) {
          Timber.v(response!!.body().toString())
      }
    })
```

Job = data

json:

```
{
  "type": "success",
  "text": "200",
  "data": [
    {
      "requestId": "5a31fc2b9af83128136f8fb3",
      "taskDetailRequestId": null,
      "clientEmail": null,
      "imageBase64": null,
      "imageLogoWidth": 0,
      "imageLogoHeight": 0,
      "additionalEmails": [],
      "clientId": "5891d6b01d58301538b578ea",
      "clientServiceAddress": {
        "id": "5891d6b01d58301538b578eb",
        "_refs": null,
        "name": "tony chew",
        "address1": null,
        "address2": null,
        "pinCode": "123123",
        "createdUserId": null,
        "lastUpdatedUserId": null,
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "organizationId": null,
        "addressType": null
      },
      "startDate": 1513311600000,
      "endDate": 1513312500000,
      "userRegId": "5891d7521d58301538b578fd",
      "requestDate": 1513225200000,
      "serviceName": "Service 1 SImple",
      "serviceRequest": null,
      "userTaskDetailsId": "5a31fc319af83128136f8fb9",
      "fromSubclient": false,
      "requestStatus": "ASSIGNED",
      "serviceRequestType": "SERVICE",
      "contractPayments": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Job.kt

```
data class Job(
  @Expose @SerializedName("type") val type: String, //success
  @Expose @SerializedName("text") val text: String, //200
  @Expose @SerializedName("data") val  data: List<Data>
)
```

Comment: Add the expected JSON and the definition of `Job`

Comment: @Pelocho  job contains type, text, and data fields

Comment: You getting string but you need `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to provide the Accept header

http://square.github.io/retrofit/#api-declaration

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@GET("mobile/tasks/user/{id}/upcoming")
  fun jobList(@Path("id") id: String): retrofit2.Call<Job>
```

But it's also possible that your request is failing for other reasons like auth and getting redirected somewhere.  Try the accept header first though.  But you don't provide enough detail in your question to answer definitively.

Comment: Is that different with this  header: {  "Accept": "*/*"}

Comment: Your question isn't reproducible or complete enough to give a definite answer.